# Ruby Slim: access local assign in Ruby engine block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

Rendering a partial Ruby Slim template, I have a little helper method embedded in an engine block. Broken-down example:

```
ruby:
  def new_record_form?
    object.new_record?
  end
```

Here, `object` is a locally-assigned variable that can be used in regular Slim code but is not accessible within the context of the engine block. Also, `local_assigns` is not available either.
How to access the variables passed to a partial within such a block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Ruby’s normal behaviour, a method cannot access local variables outside of its scope in this way — in fact it’s fairly unusual to have a such a method.

You might see such a thing when defining a class, e.g.:

```
class Foo
  object = 7

  # use object in some way in defining the class...

  def bar
    # object not available here
    puts object
  end
end
```

Here the method `bar` has no way to access `object`.

Ruby also allows syntax such as this, which is closer to what is happening in your case when your Slim code is compiled:

```
def foo
  object = 7

  def bar
    puts object
  end

end
```

But note that this *isn’t* a nested method as such, calling `foo` results in defining `bar` on the same object, but the `object` variable isn’t available in `bar`, and calling `bar` will result in an error.

In order to access variables from inside methods like this they need to be instance variables. In your example it would look something like this:

```
- @object = ...
ruby:
  def new_record_form?
    @object.new_record?
  end
```

Note that the general advice is to keep the actual code in your templates to a minimum. You might want to move this method into a helper — instance variables would be available from there.

Comment: The scoping was clear to me but I wasn't sure how the the scopes were arranged in the context of Slim processing in order to fix the problem. Without going into details of why a helper doesn't (imho) make much sense in this specific case, the instance-variable solution seems like a good approach. Thanks!